# How to Install Cuda 10.1 with Tensorflow V.2.4 RTX 2070 Super Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia

I'm new and studying Machine Learning.
When I try install nvidia cuda following instruction https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu?hl=en,
Installing failed.

To use Cuda in tensorflow 2.4, It requires Cuda v10.1 and when I try install cuda 10.1 following (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update) It deletes my graphic card driver nvidia-450 and install nvidia-418 . I think RTX 2070 SUPER doesn't support because after installing nvidia-418 my screen resolution has downgraded and doesn't work nvidia-smi command.

How to install cuda10.1 in my computer environment(Ubuntu18.04 , RTX 2070 SUPER, tensorflow v2.4)? or any available version of cuda for RTX 2070 super to use tensorflow?

Sorry short my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu 18.04, you can use `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. The version of CUDA in that package (as of January 20, 2021) is 10.1.

Once you've run that you can confirm that it is indeed 10.1 with `nvcc --version`.